# Refer from several columns in table to single another table using foreign keys?

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

I have a table in SQL Server that has 5 columns that I would like to refer to another table's rows using foreign keys.

Question: Is it possible that one row would refer to the same or different rows of a single another table via foreign keys? If yes, how can I declare it in MSSQL. Are there any special options that should be added to foreign keys so that I do not produce any errors on updating or deleting the first table's row?

Example:

```
 Table 2: 

 Id Value1 Value2  Value3
 1  aaa    bbb     ccc
 2  ddd    eee     fff
 3  aaa    bbb     ccc
 ...


  Table 1:

 Id Column1=FK to table2  Column2=FK to table2 Column3=FK to table2
 1  1                     1                    3
 2  3                     2                    1

etc.
```

Comment: This is entirely too vague for an answer. How about some tables definitions and sample data that represents the issues/concerns you have? [mcve]

Comment: @SeanLange, the whole question is how to properly specify the depicted problem. What exactly you feel is vague? I have two tables and want several columns of the first table to be foreign keys to same/different rows in second table. I ask whether it is possible technically and what options I might need to apply to FK constraints.

Comment: At the time of my response you didn't have the sample data that you have now. So in your above example you want to have 3 distinct foreign keys. One from each column is to have a foreign key to Id in table 2? That sounds to me like something has gone wrong in the design of the tables. But to specifically answer your question, yes this is possible. Did you try doing this?

Comment: I have tried to encode this using Entity Framework and it was created but the actual interaction did not work, so I resort to learn how to do it in plain SQL and go from there. What other design you would suggest? My business case does require an entity (aka table 1 entry) that utilizes several identical complex properties that would go to Table 2.

Comment: I have no idea what this is really trying to do but it has the look of repeating groups. But without knowledge of what you are modeling it is impossible to say for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't anything more complicated than a single foreign key. It has a definite smell to it that the design is less than ideal. But with no knowledge of the business requirements it is impossible to be certain or help find a better architecture.

Here is a working example as outlined in your question.

```
create table Table2
(
    Id int identity primary key
    , Value1 varchar(10)
)

create table Table1
(
    Id int identity primary key
    , Val1 int 
    , Val2 int
    , Val3 int
    , constraint FK_Table1_Table2_Val1 foreign key (Val1) references Table2(Id)
    , constraint FK_Table1_Table2_Val2 foreign key (Val2) references Table2(Id)
    , constraint FK_Table1_Table2_Val3 foreign key (Val3) references Table2(Id)
)

insert Table2 values
('first val')
, ('second')
, ('third')

insert Table1 values
(1, 1, 3)
, (3, 2, 1)
```